# Advanced replace between certain dynamic changes within strings in R

Tags: r, regex, string, dplyr

I have a sting

> "Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2red','14246,14681','Simple','2018-07-26')"

It should be replaced as

> "Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2red','14681,XXXXXX','Simple','2018-07-26')"

I've looked at `regex` functions and other string functions, they are long/difficult to edit any change and I need the easiest way to do this for an array of strings.

**Note: The 'XXXXXX' is in the position of the largest number but it replaces the value of the smallest number while retaining the ascending order.**

Here is a sample code to get started, it has the sample data and the desired data.

```
#This is the avaliable data
olddata<-data.frame(sqlcode=c("Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2red','14246,14681','Simple','37748','2018-07-26')",
                              "Functionname('parameter1green','parameter2blue','13027,13559,13914,14246,14681','Simple','24548','2018-07-26')",
                              "Functionname('parameter1white','parameter2red','13587,42254','Complex','36848','2018-07-26')",
                              "Functionname('parameter1green','parameter2green','14246','Simple','37258','2018-07-26')",
                              "Functionname('parameter1red','parameter2white','14246,14681','Complex','37568','2018-07-26')",
                              "Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2white','13587,42243','Simple','22548','2018-07-26')"),stringsAsFactors = F)

#This is the value which has to be replaced
newval="XXXXXX"

#This is how the new data should look like
#The numbers between the parameter2color and Simple/complex are supposed to be replaced with the newval in a way that the first number between them is replaced with it 
# but placed at the position of the last number
desireddata<-data.frame(sqlcode=c("Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2red','14681,XXXXXX','Simple','37748','2018-07-26')",
                              "Functionname('parameter1green','parameter2blue','13559,13914,14246,14681,XXXXXX','Simple','24548','2018-07-26')",
                              "Functionname('parameter1white','parameter2red','42254,XXXXXX','Complex','36848','2018-07-26')",
                              "Functionname('parameter1green','parameter2green','XXXXXX','Simple','37258','2018-07-26')",
                              "Functionname('parameter1red','parameter2white','14681,XXXXXX','Complex','37568','2018-07-26')",
                              "Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2white','42243,XXXXXX','Simple','22548','2018-07-26')"))
```

Comment: Is the largest number (the one to be replaced) always the last one before `Simple` or `Complex`?

Comment: And are the numbers always 5 digits?

Comment: No they are not always 5 digits, they might be 6 digits also, and the replacement is not the largest number, the position of replacement is the largest number while the number to be removed is the smallest number

Comment: *"position of replacement is the largest ... number to be removed is the smallest"*, I suspect there are more rules that would help. Are the numbers always incrementing? Are we always looking at the third parameter of five? Is that "string" always single-ticks surrounded by comma-delimited numbers with no whitespace?

Comment: Yes, the numbers are always increasing (sometimes an extra digit as well).
We are only interested in editing the third parameter.
Yes the formatting of the string is always like this, only the length of the arguments change.

Comment: So this is really just rotating the numbers: remove the left-most, shift all remaining (if any) to the left, and add the `XXXXXX`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, new rules, new code, *new test data*. I'll keep the solutions below (`gsub` and `` `regmatches<-` ``), but they don't seem to follow the rules. Here's the code that works, using the data from the OP.

```
gr1 <- gregexpr("\\(.*\\)", olddata$sqlcode)
args <- strsplit(unlist(regmatches(olddata$sqlcode, gr1)), "','")
arg3 <- sapply(args, `[[`, 3)
arg3new <- sapply(strsplit(arg3, ","), function(a) paste(c(tail(a,n=-1), newval), collapse=","))
regmatches(olddata$sqlcode, gr1) <- sapply(mapply(`[<-`, args, list(3), arg3new, SIMPLIFY=FALSE), paste, collapse="','")
olddata
#                                                                                                           sqlcode
# 1                     Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2red','14681,XXXXXX','Simple','37748','2018-07-26')
# 2 Functionname('parameter1green','parameter2blue','13559,13914,14246,14681,XXXXXX','Simple','24548','2018-07-26')
# 3                   Functionname('parameter1white','parameter2red','42254,XXXXXX','Complex','36848','2018-07-26')
# 4                        Functionname('parameter1green','parameter2green','XXXXXX','Simple','37258','2018-07-26')
# 5                   Functionname('parameter1red','parameter2white','14681,XXXXXX','Complex','37568','2018-07-26')
# 6                   Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2white','42243,XXXXXX','Simple','22548','2018-07-26')
```

Everything below this line is no longer needed.

---

---

Two methods: the first (`gsub`) will change all instances of the max number found, which may/may-not be possible or a problem; the second (`` `regmatches<-` ``) will only replace the max value returned by `which.max`, so it will always replace at most one number.

---

## 1: `gsub`

```
gr <- gregexpr("[0-9]+", olddata$sqlcode)
str( nums <- regmatches(olddata$sqlcode, gr) )
# List of 6
#  $ : chr [1:7] "1" "2" "14246" "14681" ...
#  $ : chr [1:10] "1" "2" "13027" "13559" ...
#  $ : chr [1:7] "1" "2" "13587" "42254" ...
#  $ : chr [1:6] "1" "2" "14246" "2018" ...
#  $ : chr [1:7] "1" "2" "14246" "14681" ...
#  $ : chr [1:7] "1" "2" "13587" "42243" ...
str( inds <- sapply(nums, function(n) which.max(as.integer(n))) )
#  int [1:6] 4 7 4 3 4 4
str( replacethese <- mapply(`[[`, nums, inds) )
#  chr [1:6] "14681" "14681" "42254" "14246" "14681" "42243"

mapply(function(strings,old) gsub(paste0("\\b", old, "\\b"), newval, strings),
       olddata$sqlcode, replacethese)
# [1] "Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2red','14246,XXXXXX','Simple','2018-07-26')"                    
# [2] "Functionname('parameter1green','parameter2blue','13027,13559,13914,14246,XXXXXX','Simple','2018-07-26')"
# [3] "Functionname('parameter1white','parameter2red','13587,XXXXXX','Complex','2018-07-26')"                  
# [4] "Functionname('parameter1green','parameter2green','XXXXXX','Simple','2018-07-26')"                       
# [5] "Functionname('parameter1red','parameter2white','14246,XXXXXX','Complex','2018-07-26')"                  
# [6] "Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2white','13587,XXXXXX','Simple','2018-07-26')"
```

---

## 2: `` `regmatches<-` ``

**N.B.**, this method operates in [*side-effect*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect) by changing the data in-place (within the frame); if this is a concern, operate on a copy of the data instead.

Starting with unchanged data, the only stipulation is that the strings must be `character` and not (as provided) `factor`s. (If you add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to your call to `data.frame`, `read.table`, `read.csv`, etc, this will not be a problem.)

```
olddata$sqlcode <- as.character(olddata$sqlcode)
```

We need a function to index the return values from `gregexpr`. It's straight-forward, but because the attributes need indexing as well, it just seems a little noisy:

```
index_reg <- function(gr, i) {
  newgr <- gr[i]
  attributes(newgr) <- attributes(gr)
  attr(newgr, "match.length") <- attr(newgr, "match.length")[i]
  newgr
}
```

With that, we just do this:

```
gr <- gregexpr("[0-9]+", olddata$sqlcode)                  # no change
nums <- regmatches(olddata$sqlcode, gr)                    # no change
inds <- sapply(nums, function(n) which.max(as.integer(n))) # no change
regmatches(olddata$sqlcode, mapply(index_reg, gr, inds, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)) <- newval
olddata # changed in-place, SIDE-EFFECT!
#                                                                                                   sqlcode
# 1                     Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2red','14246,XXXXXX','Simple','2018-07-26')
# 2 Functionname('parameter1green','parameter2blue','13027,13559,13914,14246,XXXXXX','Simple','2018-07-26')
# 3                   Functionname('parameter1white','parameter2red','13587,XXXXXX','Complex','2018-07-26')
# 4                        Functionname('parameter1green','parameter2green','XXXXXX','Simple','2018-07-26')
# 5                   Functionname('parameter1red','parameter2white','14246,XXXXXX','Complex','2018-07-26')
# 6                   Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2white','13587,XXXXXX','Simple','2018-07-26')
```

Comment: I like your gsub approach, although I think it will take a day for me to understand it. But I wanted the smallest number removed and replaced by "XXXXXX" not the largest. But, I need the position of the "XXXXXX" to be at the last because they are in ascending order. I think first we have to remove the smallest number than just add the "XXXXXX" after the largest number. It would really help me if you could somehow come with the logic to do that. I'm trying to do that for 2 days now

Comment: See the edit, much simpler in one way, but requires a little workaround to prevent hack-ness.

Comment: I still don't understand how this happens, can you direct me towards reading materials for the functions used. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The help pages are my first place, then I look for any R tutorial on regex (esp those that would include `regmatches`). Really, the best way to understand is to look at the return of each call to see what is going on. In general, `gregexpr` returns indices of character-ranges that match the pattern(s), and `regmatches` either (a) extracts those sub-strings, or when on the left-hand side of an assignment `<-`, it *replaces* those substrings with new values. That's about it.

Comment: So you accepted and then un-accepted the answer ... does it not work for you, or are you trying to understand it thoroughly to make sure it's doing what you need?

Comment: This code replaces all the numbers to the new values, some cases this is not supposed to happen. For example **Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2red','14246,14681','Simple','37748','2018-07-26')** is transfered to **Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2red','14681,XXXXXX','Simple','14681,XXXXXX','2018-07-26')** but the change should only happen to the third element, can this be implemented in this logic?

Comment: That wasn't included in the test data, so we need to be a bit more explicit about extracting just the third argument. That'll take a bit more elbow-grease ...

Comment: I've updated the sample data to fit my requirement. Also, there may be numbers before (in the place of paramater2color) The only thing we know for sure is that its the third argument. I'd be thrilled to have a simple solution like the one you provided

Comment: Thanks, wizard! It fits my requirement perfectly. I also love the fact that we are able to change the position of the argument, I'll definitely pass it as a parameter in a function. You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `stringr` approach replacing the last number in the group:

```r
olddata <- data.frame(
  sqlcode = c(
    "Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2red','14246,14681','Simple','2018-07-26')",
    "Functionname('parameter1green','parameter2blue','13027,13559,13914,14246,14681','Simple','2018-07-26')",
    "Functionname('parameter1white','parameter2red','13587,42254','Complex','2018-07-26')",
    "Functionname('parameter1green','parameter2green','14246','Simple','2018-07-26')",
    "Functionname('parameter1red','parameter2white','14246,14681','Complex','2018-07-26')",
    "Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2white','13587,42243','Simple','2018-07-26')"
  )
)

library(tidyverse)
desireddata <- olddata %>%
  mutate(sqlcode = str_replace(sqlcode, "\\d{5}(?=','(Simple|Complex))", "XXXXXX"))
desireddata
#>                                                                                                   sqlcode
#> 1                     Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2red','14246,XXXXXX','Simple','2018-07-26')
#> 2 Functionname('parameter1green','parameter2blue','13027,13559,13914,14246,XXXXXX','Simple','2018-07-26')
#> 3                   Functionname('parameter1white','parameter2red','13587,XXXXXX','Complex','2018-07-26')
#> 4                        Functionname('parameter1green','parameter2green','XXXXXX','Simple','2018-07-26')
#> 5                   Functionname('parameter1red','parameter2white','14246,XXXXXX','Complex','2018-07-26')
#> 6                   Functionname('parameter1blue','parameter2white','13587,XXXXXX','Simple','2018-07-26')
```

Created on 2018-08-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: I like your approach because it's the easiest to understand. Actually, I wanted the smallest number removed and replaced by "XXXXXX", not the largest. But, I need the position of the "XXXXXX" to be at the last because they are in ascending order. I think first we have to remove the smallest number than just add the "XXXXXX" after the largest number.